# App Component se muestra en todos las paginas

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

Tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de navegar por medio de los componentes en `angular`, es decir, puedo ingresar de manera correcta a la ruta donde se encuentra el componente, pero al momento de ingresar a la pagina se muestra tanto el componente principal como el componente que deberia ser cargado en la pagina.

Es decir se muestran:

- App Component
- Respuestas Component

Uno debajo del otro.

Lo que deseo es que al momento de por ejemplo ir a la ruta `/respuestas` el componente principal deje de mostrarse y se me muestre el componente de `/respuestas`

Una de las cosas que intente para resolver este problema es colocar:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Al final de cada componente, por ej:

`AppComponent.html`:

```
<></>
...
...
<app-menu></app-menu>
...
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Respuestas.html:

```
<h1>Ej</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Sin embargo esto no tuvo ningun efecto para resolver el problema.

Por el momento la estructura que tengo es la siguiente:

```
 - components
   ...menu
      ...menu.component.html
      ...menu.component.scss
      ...menu.component.spec.ts
      ...menu.component.ts

 - modulos
   ...respuestas
      ...respuestas-routing.module.ts
      ...respuestas.component.html
      ...respuestas.component.scss
      ...respuestas.component.spec.ts
      ...respuestas.component.ts
      ...respuestas.module.ts
```

y el componente principal:

```
 - app-routing.module.ts
 - app.component.html
 - app.component.scss
 - app.component.spec.ts
 - app.module.ts
```

El componente `app-menu` no posee enrutamiento, debido a que no es un componente que deba como tal mostrar información, si no que será adherido a distintas paginas, por este motivo no posee un `routing-module`.

La idea era implementar lazy loading en el aplicativo como buena practica, esta es la forma en la que intente implementar el lazy loading:

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'respuestas',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import("./modulos/respuestas/respuestas.module").then(x => x.RespuestasModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PQRSMenuComponent } from './components/pqrsmenu/pqrsmenu.component';
import { DAOPQRSService } from './model/daopqrs.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PQRSMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpClient, DAOPQRSService, PQRSMenuComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**respuestas-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RespuestasComponent } from './respuestas.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RespuestasComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RespuestasRoutingModule { }
```

**respuestas.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RespuestasRoutingModule } from './respuestas-routing.module';
import { RespuestasComponent } from './respuestas.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RespuestasComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RespuestasRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class RespuestasModule { }
```

Por el momento no he encontrado nada extraño como para que ocurra ese comportamiento tan extraño (se carga el componente principal en una pagina totalmente distinta), porque ocurre esto?, como podria resolverlo?.

**Nota**: la ruta principal (`/`) muestra solo el componente principal, lo cual es correcto, la ruta `/respuestas` muestra ambos componentes.

Navego mediante el menu anteriormente mencionado de esta manera:

**menu.component.html**:

```
<div class="h-100">
    <ul class="nav pt-3 d-flex align-items-start flex-column bg-blue h-100 pd-menu">

        <h3 class="menu-title nav-link text-white mb-3 d-block w-100" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">PQRS</h3>
        
        <li *ngFor = "let menuItem of menuLinks;" class="nav-item">
            <i class="{{ menuItem.icon }} text-white ms-2"></i>
            <a class="d-inline-block nav-link text-white" [ngClass] = "{'active': menuItem.status}" aria-current="page" routerLink='/respuestas'>{{ menuItem.title }}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Por el momento todos los links estan vinculados al mismo sitio, a manera de prueba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Para poder usar el selector de un componente compartiendolo en
> distintas paginas hay que incluirlo en un modulo luego importar ese
> modulo al modulo que contenga la pagina con la cual queremos compartir
> ese componente
> [compartiendo modulos](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/sharing-ngmodules)
> Por ejemplo creo dentro de una carpeta hola creo un modulo hola y un componente saludo El modulo hola declara y exporta al componente saludo.Este modulo hola luego puedo  exportarlo a cualquier modulo que quiera que reconozca al selector y lo pinte
> Si usas el selector en app.component.html este se compartira por todas las rutas lo indicado dejar en app.component.html solo `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`y crear un modulo si es necesario que sera el encargado de distribuir la aplicacion

```
saludo.component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-saludo',
      template: `
        <p>
          saludo works!
          Hola!!!
        </p>
      `,
      styles: [
      ]
    })
    export class SaludoComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
    hola.module.ts
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { SaludoComponent } from './saludo/saludo.component';
    
    
    
    @NgModule({
      
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations:[SaludoComponent],
      exports:[SaludoComponent]
    
    })
    export class HolaModule { }
    Asi lo podre reutilizar donde quiera por ejemplo en respuestas.module.ts
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
    import { RespuestasRoutingModule } from './respuestas-routing.module';
    import { RespuestasComponent } from './respuestas.component';
    
    
    import { HolaModule } from '../hola/hola.module';
    
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        RespuestasComponent,
        
        
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HolaModule,
        RespuestasRoutingModule
      ]
    })
    export class RespuestasModule { }
    luego en respuestas.component.html
    <p> Pagina Respuestas!!</p>
    <header>
        <p>
          <a routerLink=""
             class="button">ir a Menu </a>
        </p>
    </header>
    <app-saludo></app-saludo>
```

Ya que  de la forma que lo intentaste hacer no es posible porque

:

> El componente  se mostrara en todas las paginas
> porque asi se lo pedis al insertar su selector en app.component.html

En una SPA, todas las funcionalidades de la aplicación existen en una sola página de HTML
pra que un componente se muestre como una pagina individual hay que adjudicarle  una ruta particular

El concepto de router-outler que queres aplicar es incorrecto porque   si lo podemos requerir para navegar por paginas hijas ya que el outler de app.component.html es para las rutas superiores y las child routes necesitan un outlet independiente
[Routing en Angular](https://www.acontracorrientech.com/routing-en-angular-guia-completa-parte-5/)
se quieres que  funcione como selector en una solo en pagina interna  en particular tenes importarlo al modulo al cual pertenezca la pagina teniendo en cuenta que angular no permite declarar una misma pagina en modulos distintos

> .El index.html es en realidad el que se muestra este contiene a
>  es una etiqueta especial creada por angular
> representa a  el componente principal el cual contiene al selector
> app-root asi te mostrara al componente app al cargarse.

En el  podremos generar  algo que se muestre en todos las paginas o no por ejemplo  de acuerdo a nuestro interes sea una barra de navegacion con enrutamiento para que se muestre en todas las paginas o no mostrar nada particular y que solo contenga a `<router-outlet></router-outler>`

El cual se puede generar si por ejemplo construimos a nuestro proyecto
con ng new proyecto --routing .

Otro archivo es el main.ts en el podes ver el punto de arranque de nuestra aplicacion contiene a  `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)   .catch(err => console.error(err));`

> De acuerdo a lo anterior primero solo contiene app.component.htl a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Creamos  a un componente en una subcarpeta de la carpeta app`ng g c menu` luego
`ng g m respuestas --route=respuestas -m app-routing.module.ts`

```
// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
// es la pagina Home pero la denomino asi para seguir //tu denominacion
    path: '',
    component: MenuComponent
  },
  { path: 'respuestas', loadChildren: () => import('./respuestas/respuestas.module').then(m => m.RespuestasModule) }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
-----------------------------------
<!-- app.component.html
<app-menu></app-menu> se mostraria siempre!lo quito
-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
-----------------------------------
respuestas-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RespuestasComponent } from './respuestas.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: RespuestasComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RespuestasRoutingModule { }
-------------------------------------------------


respuestas.component.html
    <p> Pagina Respuestas!!</p>
    
    <header>
        <p>
          <a routerLink=""
             class="button">ir a Menu </a>
        </p>
    </header>
    ----------------------------------
    menu.component.html
    <p>Pagina Menu!!!</p>
    <header>
        <p>
          <a routerLink="respuestas"
             class="button">ir a pagina Respuestas </a>
        </p>
    </header>
    ----------------------------------
```

Luego vinculo a una barra de navegación en todas las rutas que tenga un vinculo a la pagina Respuestas aprovechando el html generado por Angular y teniendo en cuenta el routing  `<span><a routerLink="/respuestas" style="color:rgba(253, 253, 211, 0.877);"> Respuestas </a></span>`

```
<style>
    :host {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #333;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      margin: 8px 0;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .spacer {
      flex: 1;
    }

    .toolbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 60px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #1976d2;
      color: white;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .toolbar img {
      margin: 0 16px;
    }

    .toolbar #twitter-logo {
      height: 40px;
      margin: 0 8px;
    }

    .toolbar #youtube-logo {
      height: 40px;
      margin: 0 16px;
    }

    .toolbar #twitter-logo:hover,
    .toolbar #youtube-logo:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .content {
      display: flex;
      margin: 82px auto 32px;
      padding: 0 16px;
      max-width: 960px;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }

    svg.material-icons {
      height: 24px;
      width: auto;
    }

    svg.material-icons:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 8px;
    }

    .card svg.material-icons path {
      fill: #888;
    }

    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .card {
      all: unset;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      background-color: #fafafa;
      height: 40px;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 0 8px 16px;
      padding: 16px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    .card-container .card:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .card.card-small {
      height: 16px;
      width: 168px;
    }

    .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card) {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card):hover {
      transform: translateY(-3px);
      box-shadow: 0 4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    }

    .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card):hover .material-icons path {
      fill: rgb(105, 103, 103);
    }



    .card.highlight-card {
      background-color: #1976d2;
      color: white;
      font-weight: 600;
      border: none;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 30%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .card.card.highlight-card span {
      margin-left: 60px;
    }

    svg#rocket {
      width: 80px;
      position: absolute;
      left: -10px;
      top: -24px;
    }

    svg#rocket-smoke {
      height: calc(100vh - 95px);
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 180px;
      z-index: -10;
    }

    a,
    a:visited,
    a:hover {
      color: #1976d2;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #125699;
    }

    .terminal {
      position: relative;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 600px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding-top: 45px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: rgb(15, 15, 16);
    }

    .terminal::before {
      content: "\2022 \2022 \2022";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 4px;
      background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
      color: #c2c3c4;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 2rem;
      line-height: 0;
      padding: 14px 0;
      text-indent: 4px;
    }

    .terminal pre {
      font-family: SFMono-Regular,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,monospace;
      color: white;
      padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .circle-link {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      border-radius: 40px;
      margin: 8px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
      transition: 1s ease-out;
    }

    .circle-link:hover {
      transform: translateY(-0.25rem);
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    footer {
      margin-top: 8px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      line-height: 20px;
    }

    footer a {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .github-star-badge {
      color: #24292e;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 3px 10px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(27,31,35,.2);
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,#fafbfc,#eff3f6 90%);
      margin-left: 4px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .github-star-badge:hover {
      background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,#f0f3f6,#e6ebf1 90%);
      border-color: rgba(27,31,35,.35);
      background-position: -.5em;
    }

    .github-star-badge .material-icons {
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      margin-right: 4px;
    }

    svg#clouds {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: -160px;
      left: -230px;
      z-index: -10;
      width: 1920px;
    }

    /* Responsive Styles */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .card-container > *:not(.circle-link) ,
      .terminal {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .card:not(.highlight-card) {
        height: 16px;
        margin: 8px 0;
      }

      .card.highlight-card span {
        margin-left: 72px;
      }

      svg#rocket-smoke {
        right: 120px;
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
      svg#rocket-smoke {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Toolbar -->
  <div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <img
      width="40"
      alt="Angular Logo"
      src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg=="
    />
  <span></span>
  <span><a routerLink="/respuestas" style="color:rgba(253, 253, 211, 0.877);">Respuestas</a></span>

    
    <div class="spacer"></div>
      <a aria-label="Angular on twitter" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://twitter.com/angular" title="Twitter">
        <svg id="twitter-logo" height="24" data-name="Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
          <rect width="400" height="400" fill="none"/>
          <path d="M153.62,301.59c94.34,0,145.94-78.16,145.94-145.94,0-2.22,0-4.43-.15-6.63A104.36,104.36,0,0,0,325,122.47a102.38,102.38,0,0,1-29.46,8.07,51.47,51.47,0,0,0,22.55-28.37,102.79,102.79,0,0,1-32.57,12.45,51.34,51.34,0,0,0-87.41,46.78A145.62,145.62,0,0,1,92.4,107.81a51.33,51.33,0,0,0,15.88,68.47A50.91,50.91,0,0,1,85,169.86c0,.21,0,.43,0,.65a51.31,51.31,0,0,0,41.15,50.28,51.21,51.21,0,0,1-23.16.88,51.35,51.35,0,0,0,47.92,35.62,102.92,102.92,0,0,1-63.7,22A104.41,104.41,0,0,1,75,278.55a145.21,145.21,0,0,0,78.62,23" fill="#fff"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <a aria-label="Angular on YouTube" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://youtube.com/angular" title="YouTube">
        <svg id="youtube-logo" height="24" width="24" data-name="Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#fff">
          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
          <path d="M21.58 7.19c-.23-.86-.91-1.54-1.77-1.77C18.25 5 12 5 12 5s-6.25 0-7.81.42c-.86.23-1.54.91-1.77 1.77C2 8.75 2 12 2 12s0 3.25.42 4.81c.23.86.91 1.54 1.77 1.77C5.75 19 12 19 12 19s6.25 0 7.81-.42c.86-.23 1.54-.91 1.77-1.77C22 15.25 22 12 22 12s0-3.25-.42-4.81zM10 15V9l5.2 3-5.2 3z"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
  </div>

  <div class="content" role="main">

    <!-- Highlight Card -->
    <div class=" card.card-small ">

      <svg id="rocket" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="101.678" height="101.678" viewBox="0 0 101.678 101.678">
        <title>Rocket Ship</title>
        <g id="Group_83" data-name="Group 83" transform="translate(-141 -696)">
          <circle id="Ellipse_8" data-name="Ellipse 8" cx="50.839" cy="50.839" r="50.839" transform="translate(141 696)" fill="#dd0031"/>
          <g id="Group_47" data-name="Group 47" transform="translate(165.185 720.185)">
            <path id="Path_33" data-name="Path 33" d="M3.4,42.615a3.084,3.084,0,0,0,3.553,3.553,21.419,21.419,0,0,0,12.215-6.107L9.511,30.4A21.419,21.419,0,0,0,3.4,42.615Z" transform="translate(0.371 3.363)" fill="#fff"/>
            <path id="Path_34" data-name="Path 34" d="M53.3,3.221A3.09,3.09,0,0,0,50.081,0,48.227,48.227,0,0,0,18.322,13.437c-6-1.666-14.991-1.221-18.322,7.218A33.892,33.892,0,0,1,9.439,25.1l-.333.666a3.013,3.013,0,0,0,.555,3.553L23.985,43.641a2.9,2.9,0,0,0,3.553.555l.666-.333A33.892,33.892,0,0,1,32.647,53.3c8.55-3.664,8.884-12.326,7.218-18.322A48.227,48.227,0,0,0,53.3,3.221ZM34.424,9.772a6.439,6.439,0,1,1,9.106,9.106,6.368,6.368,0,0,1-9.106,0A6.467,6.467,0,0,1,34.424,9.772Z" transform="translate(0 0.005)" fill="#fff"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
```

> En una SPA, todas las funcionalidades de la aplicación existen en una
> sola página de HTML
>
> router-outlet es una directiva del enrutador de  Angular sirve para
> definir el espacio en el cual    se inyectaran los componentes para
> decidir cual componente mostrar es un contenedor dinamico

. Por defecto todos los componentes son hijos del componente AppComponent,
por lo que si incluímos esta etiqueta dentro de la vista de AppComponent.router-outler produce que la ruta `/respuestas`
sea reconocida .Ya que en Angular tenemos al index.html y todas las paginas accionaran con el intercambiandose
segun el codigo escrito

Para poder navegar cada ruta es entregada por el index.html el sistema de routing es el que reconocera la ruta y nos permite   navegar tambien por rutas internas sin estar siempre en la pantalla principal de la aplicacion.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, sip, luego de un tiempo me di cuenta de mi error y basicamente para corregirlo movi todo lo que tenia en el `app.component` a un componente aparte. Sin embargo tu respuesta me ayudo a aclarar el funcionamiento de angular y porque se daba este comportamiento.

Comment: Si hay que tener en cuanta como inicia angular la aplicación por eso un selector en app.component.html  será visible en todos lados y también tener en cuenta al path:'',porque podemos sin quererlo duplicar el contenido de app.component.html .me alegra que te fuera de utilidad siempre pensarlo con módulos y si queremos compartir componentes compartir modulos

Answer (score 0):

> ... puedo ingresar de manera correcta a la ruta donde se encuentra el
> componente, pero al momento de ingresar a la pagina se muestra tanto
> el componente principal como el componente que deberia ser cargado en
> la pagina.

Cuando añades así las rutas en `AppRoutingModule` e incluyes la etiqueta `router-outlet` en `AppComponent`, lo que haces es construir una Single Page Application (SPA) ([enlace 1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), [enlace 2](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial)). En una SPA se actualizan los contenidos de una misma página HTML según la ruta. En tu caso, los componentes irían apareciendo en `app.component.html`, justo debajo de `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Por lo tanto, lo que te ocurre es justo el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: Vale, entonces seria el comportamiento normal que deberia generar la aplicacion, sin embargo lo que deseo es que solo se muestre el contenido de la pagina actual y no todo en una sola pagina, que forma habria de hacerlo sin tener que estar poniendo un script en cada componente o cosas asi

Answer (score -1):

Imagino que lo que voy explicar a continuacion es lo que buscas y espero que te ayuda en tu problema.
En app.component.html hay un  en app.routing tenemos los modulos o componentes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'test', component: MytestComponent },
  { path: 'business', loadChildren: () => import('./business/business.module').then(m => m.BusinessModule) },
  { path: 'favorite', loadChildren: () => import('./favorite/favorite.module').then(m => m.FavoriteModule) },
  { path: '**', loadChildren: () => import('./pagenotfound/pagenotfound.module').then(m => m.PagenotfoundModule) },
];
```

tal comopuedes ver hay un enlace a otro modulo con el nombre **business** y tiene las mismas caracteristicas, que app.component (tine app.module, app-routing etc).
en este modulo al añadir las routas o otros componentes que solo pertenecesn a este modulo.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: BusinessComponent, children: [
    { path: 'lista', component: ProductsComponent },
    { path: 'inventory', component: InventoryComponent },
    { path: 'addproduct', component: AeproductComponent },
    { path: 'editproduct/:id', component: AeproductComponent },
    { path: 'edit', component: EditComponent },
    { path: 'category', component: CategorylistComponent },
    { path: 'services', component: ServicoComponent },
    { path: 'setting', component: SettingComponent },
    { path: 'profil', component: ProfilComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    { path: 'purchase', loadChildren: () => import('../historypurchase/historypurchase.module').then(m => m.HistorypurchaseModule) },
    { path: 'orders', loadChildren: () => import('../historyorder/historyorder.module').then(m => m.HistoryorderModule) }
  ]
}];
```

entonces todo los componentes o modulos hay que poner como children y al indicar el link para cada uno hay indicar que pertenece a este modulo.

```
links: myRoute[] = [
    { icon: 'list', name: this.tr.product, url: '/business/lista' },
    { icon: 'inventory', name: this.tr.invent, url: '/business/inventory' },
    { icon: 'category', name: this.tr.category, url: '/business/category' },
    { icon: 'settings_applications', name: this.tr.servis, url: '/business/services' },
    { icon: 'settings', name: this.tr.sett, url: '/business/setting' },
    // { icon: 'perm_media', name: this.tr.img, url: '/business/images', css: 'active-item' }, 
    { icon: 'shop_two', name: this.tr.purchhistory, url: '/business/purchase' },
    { icon: 'list_alt', name: this.tr.orderhistory, url: '/business/orders' },
    { icon: 'admin_panel_settings', name: this.tr.account, url: '/business/profil' },
    { icon: 'contact_mail', name: this.tr.contact, url: '/business/contact' },
  ];
```

y por supuesto lista ne navigacion.

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index"
     routerLinkActive="active-item" [routerLink]="link.url"
        (isActiveChange)="isActivChang()">
        <span matLine>{{link.name}}</span>
        <mat-icon>{{link.icon}}</mat-icon>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Y el resultado final
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y los modulos o componentes tiene que pertenecer al modulo que les coresponde y no al modulo principal.

Comment: el dice "El componente app-menu no posee enrutamiento, debido a que no es un componente que deba como tal mostrar información, si no que será adherido a distintas paginas" y ese es el problema que manifiesta En tu respuesta te réferis al path busines que seria el similar a el de el respuestas con el cual no refiere problema el problema es que menú se le muestra por todos lados

Comment: "los modulos o componentes tiene que pertenecer al modulo que les coresponde y no al modulo principal." esto indica que los modulos/componentes que quieres mostrar solo en el modulo Respuesta tienen que estar añadidas en este modulo y no en ningun otro.

Comment: podes compartir módulos y así componentes. No dice tener problema para mostrar a respuestas se queja  de que menú y respuesta se muestran juntos al ir a la ruta respuestas eso es porque usa al selector menú en app.component.html

Comment: Hola, no, en este caso el inconveniente no era exactamente que el menu se mostrase en todos los componentes, ya que de hecho este se muestra en todos y ese es el comportamiento que deseo, lo que no deseaba era que siendo la pagina principal, aparte del menu se me renderizase cosas dentro del `app.component` que no quiero que se muestren a la hora de navegar a otro componente, por ejemplo, si tuviese una imagen dentro del `app.component` esta solo deberia ser mostrada en el `app.component`, y no en las demas rutas, comportamiento el cual (como ejemplo, ocurre en este caso).